# how to get specific string from string(url)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**i have string like this**

http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/globalAssets/imgLoading_30x30.gif" imgsel="0" alt="Image is

and i want to get string from the first(http) to the (gif) word and ignore all to the end

Comment: What is your string _exactly_ and what do you want as a result? Can you please show example input and outputs?

Comment: Why do you have half the inside of an HTML `<img>` tag and want to do string operations on that? Why don't you use HtmlAgilityPack or something like that to parse HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the string till gif, use the `substring` method

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // your code goes here
         String myString = "http://i...content-available-to-author-only...c.com//pictures//aw//pics//globalAssets//imgLoading_30x30.gif//imgsel=\"0\" alt=\"Image\"";
          Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(0,myString.IndexOf("gif")+3));
    }
}
```

Ouput:

`http://i...content-available-to-author-only...c.com//pictures//aw//pics//globalAssets//imgLoading_30x30.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Just store the url in string variable after that use split function
using ('//').Then store value set to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can below function,
pass http in start and gif in end variable

```
 string getsubstring(string text, string start, string end)
{
    text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(start));
    text = text.Substring(0,text.IndexOf(end));
    return text;

}
```